# Cypher - a statement that creates two sequential links

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create a cypher query that will allow me to add a child comment to a parent comment. I have written some cypher that does work, but I want to also attach the author's relationship to the new child comment and my code doesn't do that (it doesn't do anything other than create the child comment).

Here is my code:

```
MATCH (c:Comment{GUID:"01f6ffa4-b481-4495-9e9c-ffca6dcc510e"})
MERGE (cc:Comment{user: "John Doe", text:"TEST", timestamp: "now", actionId:apoc.create.uuid()})
MERGE (c)<-[:COMMENTED_ON]-(cc)
WITH cc AS comment
MATCH (u:User {name: "John Doe"})
MERGE (comment)<-[:ADDED]-(u)
```

All things inside strings are dummy data

I'm not 100% clear on what I need to use the `with` statement for, but I can't run the query without a `with` statement there.

Thanks!

Comment: `c` and `cc` seem to store the guid for the comment under 2 different property names ('GUID' and 'actionId'). This will cause problems for you when you want to, say, find a comment by its guid. You should use consistent property naming.

Answer (score 0):

The `WITH` clause is required because you are performing another `MATCH` after you have performed a mutating operation. The `WITH` statement effectively partitions different clauses in your query. Each clause is like a step in a pipeline. Only the identifiers that are in the `WITH` statement are passed onto the next section.

If you want to achieve this without the `WITH` statement you could do this. In this case since each `MATCH` and `MERGE` presumably has a single result. But if there were multiple results per statement (i.e. more than one *John Doe*) it would result in a larger cartesian product and likely an unintended consequence.

```
MATCH (u:User {name: "John Doe"})
MATCH (c:Comment {GUID:"01f6ffa4-b481-4495-9e9c-ffca6dcc510e"})
MERGE (cc:Comment {user: "John Doe", text:"TEST", timestamp: "now", actionId:apoc.create.uuid()})
MERGE (c)<-[:COMMENTED_ON]-(cc)
MERGE (cc)<-[:ADDED]-(u)
```

Comment: Hey Dave, thanks for answering. I tried running your query in my browser but unfortunately it only returned `(no changes, no records)`. I'm struggling to debug Cypher/Neo4j so I'm not sure what more information I could give you to here?

Comment: do these statements both return results? 

`MATCH (u:User {name: "John Doe"}) RETURN u;` 

`MATCH (c:Comment {GUID:"01f6ffa4-b481-4495-9e9c-ffca6dcc510e"}) RETURN c;`

Comment: Yeah they do - I've actually done a slightly hacky way of getting around the problem for now, by having an extra query that assigns a user to the child comment so I'm just triggering two queries to run one after the other for now